# iPhone: Removing rounded corners from table view cell

Tags: iphone, tableview, rounded-corners

i have a table view in my application which shows rounded corners by default.

Is there any way to remove the rounded corners.

I have `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in place and included the frame work as well.

eve the following code does not work

```
 self.clipsToBounds = NO;
 self.table.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
```

can any one suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What doesn't work? Compiler or Runtime?

Answer (score 3):

For a UITableViewStyleGrouped cell, you'll need to change the backgroundView on your cell.

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundView = bg;

[bg release]; // if you're not using ARC
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `UITableViewStyleGrouped` on your table view? If so change the style to `UITableViewStylePlain` and the cells will be rectangulars without rounded corners.